Crash when scrolling a UITableView after applying mask to an image
I am applying a mask to an image in a custom table cell. The mask works correctly but as soon as I scroll the table I get a Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value on the mask UIImageView.
Here is my code (I've ommitted some variable declarations for brevity):
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LeagueTableCell") as UITableViewCell?
    
    let badgeFgr = cell?.viewWithTag(9) as! UIImageView
    let badgeMask = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UIImageView

    // Set the image
    if let theImage = UIImage(named: imageString) {
      badgeFgr.image = theImage.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
      badgeFgr.tintColor = fgrCol
        
      // Apply the mask
      badgeMask.image = UIImage(named: "maskShape")
      badgeFgr.mask = badgeMask
    }

    return cell!
  }

When I scroll the table the app crashes and the Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value occurs on this line:
    let badgeMask = cell?.viewWithTag(4) as! UIImageView

When I show the image without applying the mask (by removing the lines below) it shows the image without masking and it doesn't crash when scrolling:
    // Apply the mask
    theMask.image = UIImage(named: "maskShape")
    theImage.mask = theMask

So what is the correct way to apply a mask to an image in a custom tableview cell?

You're doing a bunch of things incorrectly... Have you designed your "LeagueTableCell " cell in Storyboard / Interface Builder or via code? Do you have a class for your cell? If so, show us the code for your cell class.

I have set up "LeagueTableCell" in Storyboard but I am not using @IBOutlet to connect badgeFgr and badgeMask. I use tags instead. Is that wrong? I don't have any code for my cell class.

You do not need to use a custom cell class and/or @IBOutlet connections... but in the long run you would probably save yourself some headaches -- particularly if you ever have someone else working on the code with you. Also, you should always safely unwrap optionals, as opposed to chaining ? and ! on your variables. To fix your immediate error, see the answer I posted.

The reason you are getting the error is because this line:
badgeFgr.mask = badgeMask

removes that image view.
Instead of trying to use a pre-added image view in your cell prototype, apply the mask like this:
// Apply the mask
if let maskImg = UIImage(named: "maskShape") {
    // create a NEW image view to use as the mask
    let imgV = UIImageView(frame: badgeFgr.bounds)
    imgV.image = maskImg
    badgeFgr.mask = imgV
}


Thanks @DonMag that worked - your help is much appreciated. I take on board your previous comments as well.
